# ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to get the AjaxControlToolkit (ACT) Auto complete extender working.
It was working briefly but has now stopped working and I can't figure out why. I haven't changed changed anything in my project that I can see would affect this.

I have even created a brand new VS2013 project and tried to implement this but still no joy.

I see several references to "ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager" but I cannot find a reference for this anywhere. I have tried installing the toolkit from a download as well as via NUGET and it simply will not work.

I have tried every example on here, at least 20 of them or more and still not joy. If you have it working please post your code because mine doesn't work and its pointless posting it be cause i have tried absolutely everything suggested here

Any help would be much appreciated as I really dont want to engineer something unelegant to get around this.

Thanks loads

[UPDATE]
ToolkitScriptManager is removed from ACT 15.1 see [here](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ToolkitScriptManager%20Removed%20in%20v15.1%2C%20Use%20ScriptManager) So that answers this question but the autocomplete still is not working

[UPDATE]

Here is an example I put togetgher, which still does not work with or without the `[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]` directive

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWebSite.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
            MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
            CompletionInterval="100" 
            ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
            runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="TextBox1"></cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestWebSite
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
        {
            string[] s = {"a","b","c","d"};

            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to see the the `AjaxControlToolkit` on your toolbox?

Comment: I can add `AjaxControlToolkit` with no issues at all. I can see the list of components in my toolbox correctly. I just can't get the auto complete to work :(

Comment: did you have another page that have `ScriptManager`?

Comment: The scriptmanager is just above the textbox

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the AJAX Control Toolkit Library by putting the following line just below the @PageDirective

this is the ajaxtoolkit

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

then this is the example to call ajaxtoolkit

```
<cc1:toolkitYouWantToUse/>
```

thasts it

Comment: Nope, that does not work either. I created a brand new project is VS2013. and when you place an autocomplete on the page the IDE adds this line for you. The auto complete still does not work. I see no errors it just doesnt do anything

Comment: you need to DL the DLL of ajax

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have it working. I created a brand new test projects in VS2013. I used the developer features of Google Chrome to debug and saw I was constantly getting a 500 error. In my experience I've usually caused this by getting my web addresses wrong so that led me to checking that the web service was working. (See further down)

After fixing that problem and knowing that the web service was OK I engaged in some trial and error, and the steps below solved the problem. I now have the AutoCompleteExtender working in all my projects using this same method.

(This may not be the way to do it but I know it works for me)

1. Remove the nuget installed version of the AjaxControlToolkit (ACT)
2. Manually add the reference to the ACT dll that I had downloaded, get the latest version from [here](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/).
3. Add a .asmx file to your project with the WebMethod defined as below. You can actually call the method any name you like the profile (e.g. parameters and return type) must remain the same. There may be other variations but I don't know what they are. I just know that this configuration worked for me.
4. Re-add the AutoCompleteControl. the VS IDE will add the @Register directive for you

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
            ServicePath="WebService1.asmx"                
            MinimumPrefixLength="0" 
            CompletionInterval="100" 
            ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
            runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="TextBox1"></cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace TestWebSite
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)//, string contextKey)
        {
            string[] s = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

            return s;
        }
    }
}
//List<string> works just as well as string[]
```

5. Run the project, manually navigate to the .asmx page and make sure that the function returns the results you expect. VS knows your running in debug so will let you add parameters and call the web method.
   [image]

[image]